# NSPredicate: Unable To Parse String

Tags: ios, nspredicate

Im doing predicate to fetch all transaction within specific date range based on transaction type.

Here is the predicate:

```
NSString *predicate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(date >= %@ AND date < %@) AND (%@)", from, to, defaultType];
```

Here is the complete code:

```
- (NSArray *)transactionFromMonth:(NSInteger)fromMonth toMonth:(NSInteger)toMonth ofTypes:(NSArray *)transactionTypes
{
   // get the current calendar of the device
   NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

   // create date components using current calendar
   NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];

   // get year
   NSInteger currentYear = [components year];

   // create fromDate (The first day of the month) using the current year, passing month, and 1 as the day
   // to form the starting day of the month
   // e.g when toMonth has a value of 1, then the resulting
   // date will be January 1, (current year of the device's calendar)
   NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
   [comps setDay:1];
   [comps setMonth:fromMonth];
   [comps setYear:currentYear];
   NSDate *from = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];


   // create toDate
   //
   // Set your month here
   [comps setMonth:toMonth];

   // get the number of days of "to" month
   NSRange range = [calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                               inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit
                              forDate:[calendar dateFromComponents:comps]];

   [comps setDay:range.length+1];

   NSDate *to = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

   NSLog(@"to Months %@", to);
   NSString *defaultType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type = %d", [[transactionTypes objectAtIndex:0] integerValue]];

   NSMutableString *types = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString: defaultType ];
   for  ( int i = 1; i < transactionTypes.count; i++ )
   {
      [defaultType stringByAppendingFormat:@" OR type = %d", [[transactionTypes objectAtIndex:i] integerValue] ];
   }

   // here is the predicate causing the error
   // 
   //
   NSString *predicate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(date >= %@ AND date < %@) AND (%@)", from, to, defaultType];
   return [self.transaction filteredSetUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicate]].allObjects;
}
```

Here is the declaration of transaction model:
Note:  .h and .m of the below model is autogenerated.

[image]

Here is the sample call:

```
// I want to retrieve all transaction from January 1 to January 31 in device's current calendar year of type kTransactionTypeAddFund (which has the value of 0)
[self transactionFromMonth:1 toMonth:1 ofTypes:@[ @(kTransactionTypeAddFund) ]];
```

Result:

> reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(date >= 2014-12-31
>   16:00:00 +0000 AND date < 2015-01-31 16:00:00 +0000) AND (type = 0)"'

Comment: At first sight (I'm not testing this and I haven't using NSPredicate in quite a while), I would say that you either output those dates as integers or you need to quote them, but I'm not sure

Comment: Adding quotes to date will treat them as NSString. So date comparison would not be possible.

Comment: What _is_ your predicate format? You have shown an error message but not your code. Show what _you_ are doing, please.

Comment: What about using timestamps?

Comment: The predicate is working by removing `AND (type = 0)`.

Comment: What about `(type == 0)`?

Comment: Still got the error using `(type == 0)`.

Comment: What values are you actually passing here? What are from, to, and defaultType? Don't you _want_ to show your code? How can I test this on my own machine if you don't provide _code_? It seems to me that providing a reproducible test case would be the merest courtesy to others if you want them to go to the trouble of trying to help you. What's so hard about that?

Comment: And what does this have to do with NSPredicate? I see no NSPredicate in this story. Your whole question makes no sense.

Comment: And why does the error message mention `type`? I see no `type` anywhere in the code you've provided. Come on, be honest and show what you are really doing. Do you want help or not? If you do, stop lying and concealing.

Comment: So don't you mean `SELF.type`?

Comment: What's the difference between `type` and `SELF.type`?

Comment: What matt says -- you should be using `predicateWithFormat`, not `stringWithFormat`.  Otherwise NSPredicate has no idea that the dates are NSDate objects -- they look just like random characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `stringWithFormat:` and `predicateWithFormat:` function differently.  Specifically, `predicateWithFormat:` will escape and/or quote strings as necessary where stringWithFormat won't.  You need to create the individual predicates with `predicateWithFormat:` and then create the conjunction using a conjunction predicate:

```
NSMutableArray* types = [NSMutableArray new];

for  ( int i = 0; i < transactionTypes.count; i++ )
{
    [types addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %@", [transactionTypes objectAtIndex:i]]];
}

// Make a compound predicate with "or" for all the types
NSPredicate*    typePredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:types];

// Create the date part of the predicate
NSPredicate*    datePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@ AND date < %@)", from, to];

// merge the type and date parts of the predicate into a single
// and predicate
NSPredicate*    predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[ typePredicate, datePredicate]];
```

Alternatively, and easier, just take advantage of predicates IN operator...

```
NSPredicate*    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@ AND date < %@ AND type IN %@", from, to, transactionTypes];
```

Comment: Thanks. The alternate answer is easier indeed.

Answer (score 3):

What I suggest you do is (1) pull that last line apart into more statements, and (2) drop the whole `stringWithFormat:` thing, because `predicateWithFormat:` *is* a format string, so you are just confusing yourself with an extra level of indirection. This test compiles and runs just fine:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = 
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
         @"(date >= %@ AND date < %@) AND (type = %@)", 
         [NSDate new], [NSDate new], @0];
```

That suggests that you should be able to do what you're trying to do if you simplify and do it in easy stages that you can understand and debug. Do what I'm doing here - form *just the predicate* on one line, using `predicateWithFormat:` as intended. Once you've got the predicate to compile, the rest is easy.

Notice, by the way, that I'm passing an *object* (an NSNumber) where `%@` is expected. You can't use scalars here (like plain old `0`). If you want to pass `0` you need something like `%d`.

One final suggestion: it looks like you're trying to form a complex predicate whose terms are conditional, like sometimes adding extra OR terms. The way to do that is to learn about things like NSCompoundPredicate - that's what it's for. Don't try to cheat and do it all with a single string.

Comment: Thank for your answer. This leads me to the correct solution.